# Jodit editor fullscreen causes toolbar to hide behind the bootstrap navbar

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using the latest bootstrap.min.css v4.1.3 and xdan/Jodit editor v3.1.92
When clicking on the fullscreen button, the editor's toolbar hides behind the bootstrap navbar. Is there a way to fix this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple CSS option you need to have the z-index value superior of bootstrap navbar.

For example :

```
.jodit_fullsize {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this my self. it looks like it adds a class of jodit_fullsize_box to the body, wrapper, content, content-wrapper,container, row and col classes. I just used css to hide the button, so you can't click it. Not an elegant solution, I know but it will serve me for the time being.

```
.jodit_toolbar_btn-fullsize{
display:none !important;
}
```